# How to remove NavigationView item background

Tags: android, android-navigationview, material-components-android, material-components

This seems like it should be trivial with the `itemBackground` attribute, but for some reason, it isn't working. 
As shown below, I can successfully add my own background (in blue), but the original ripple (grey rectangle) is still visible.
Setting `itemBackground` to `null` doesn't seem to do the trick either.

[image]

My navigation view:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"
    app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />
```

(Basically untouched style wise from the generated view)

My ripple:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/accent_ripple">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:right="8dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
                android:topRightRadius="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

My app theme also extends `Theme.MaterialComponents`, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You have tried setting checkable= false inside menu items.

Comment: Just tried and it doesn't have any effect unfortunately

Comment: Try setting app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: Even with transparent, there is still the original ripple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a custom shape in your Item Background don't use the `app:itemBackground` attribute.

Use the **`app:itemShapeAppearanceOverlay`** and the **`app:itemShapeFillColor`** attributes:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:itemShapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Item"
    app:itemShapeFillColor="@color/nav_item_shape_fill"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.NavigationView"
    ../>
```

where:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.Item" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">16dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">0dp</item>
  </style>
```

and the color selector is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_activated="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

[image]

Currently there isn't a method to remove the ripple outside the shape in the item.
However you can use the `android:theme` to override the color used by the ripple.

```
  <style name="ThemeOverlay.NavItem.Ripple" parent="">
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
```

Check this [issue for updates](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/677).

Comment: Late reply. I did see your issue created at https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/677, but this still doesn't seem to work for me. Are there any parent themes that are required for this?

Comment: Marking this as the fix, though the real fix is setting the control highlight to transparent via android:theme, as mentioned in the github issue

Comment: @AllanW Thanks for feedback. I updated the answer with my solution in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

just you can do like this :

```
 <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_navigation_header" />

        <include layout="@layout/layout_navigation" />
    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Are you basically reimplementing a navigation view with your own layout here? I'd like to avoid that ideally, since I"m sure others have used it and created their own ripples

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you override it with your own drawable? You can use your own color and effect or even make the ripple effect transparent with hex

```
#ffffffff
```

or

```
@android:color/transparent
```

Comment: That's what I've attempted to do with `itemBackground`. `nav_item_background` is my own drawable as shown. The change does work, but for some reason there is still the original background there